# How to check if number is string or integer in python using if else

Tags: python

I am new to Python (30 minutes). I want to know how to identify whether the number is an integer or a string, and proceed with the result using if else.

My code is:

```
number = input("enter the number \n")

integer = int(number)

if integer.is_integer():

    if integer > 0:
        print("positive ", integer)
    elif integer < 0:
        print("Negative ", integer)
    else:
        print("Number is", integer)
else:
    print("Enter integer value")
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem then?

Comment: All input will be a string. If it's not possible to cast that to an integer then `integer = int(number)` will fail anyway with `ValueError`. You can wrap it in a `try`/`except` block.

Comment: If `int` is able to parse the number `is_integer` will *always* return `True`...

Comment: It shows an error, It my bad I just add a wrong syntax.

Comment: However, This is working

number = input("enter the number \n")
if number.isdigit():
    integer = int(number)
    if integer > 0:
        print("positive ", integer)
    elif integer < 0:
        print("Negative ", integer)
    else:
        print("Number is", integer)

else:
    print("Enter integer value")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
number = input("enter the number \n")

try:
    integer = int(number)

    if integer > 0:
        print "positive", integer
    elif integer < 0:
        print "Negative", integer
    else:
        print "Number is", integer

except ValueError:
    print("Enter integer value")
```

Comment: Thanx Bemmu, It's working :)

Comment: I try to keep `except` blocks as close to the cause of error as possible.

Comment: @PeterWood OK, how should I change my response?

Answer (score -2):

Python provides doc-typing feature which means no matter if a value defined as a String or Number. So you must only check if the value conforms numerical properties or not using ***isnumeric()***. This method returns true if all characters in the string are numeric, false otherwise.

```
str = u"hello100";  
print str.isnumeric() #returns false

str = u"123900";
print str.isnumeric() #returns true
```

Comment: Except for the fact that this does not work when the input is for example `"-123"`.

Comment: Besides, it's **duck**-typing.